# Como atribuir uma class css nos formulários do django

Tags: css, python, django

Fala galera, tudo bem?
Então a bucha de hoje é a seguinte, desejo adicionar por padrão um css nos meu formulários gerados no django, dei uma pesquisada achei algumas coisas mas nada resolvia o meu "problema". 
Queria saber se tem alguma forma de adicionar uma class css?
Segue a baixo meu código atual do form.py e minha models.py respectivativamente

```
#form.py

from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Transacao

class TransacaoForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Transacao
    fields = ['dt_transaco','descricao','valor','categoria','observacoes']

#models.py
class Transacao(models.Model):
    dt_transaco = models.DateTimeField()
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    observacoes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = 'Transações'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, você não colocou nenhum código de seus templates aí - se quer uma classe CSS no `form` de HTML, é nos templates que precisa por, manualmente - as classes do `django.forms` até tem métodos de renderização para HTML, mas a tag `Form` vem sempre no template - os objetos em Python são renderizados para os textos, ajuda, e widgets que vão *dentro* do form.

Já se quiser adicionar atributos `class` customizados nos controles (widgets) gerados por Django form, aí é outra conversa - 
Você pode associar classes de html a cada controle de um form passando o parâmetro `attrs` ao criar o campo - a documentação está aqui:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances
```

Claro que, como nesse caso, você está usando um modelform, isso implicaria em que você teria que declarar os fields manualmente na classe que herda de `ModelForm`, para passar o parâmetro `attrs`  para o widget.

Se quiser manter tudo automático e alterar só o attrs, dá pra fazer isso logo depois de declarar a classe, e manipular o obejto `Field` manualmente - a criaçao de classes de form do Django tem uma customização que faz com que sejam diferentes de classes normais de Python  - os `Fields`  de uma classe  `django.forms.Form` ficam em dicionários dentro da classe, e não direto como atributos da classe - todos são listados dentro de um dicionário chamado `base_fields`. Num objeto do tipo `Field`, você pode acessar diretamente o atributo `widget` e customizar o atributo `attrs` do mesmo (que é um dicionário Python)- esses  `attrs` serão renderizados para html:

```
class TransacaoForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Transacao
    fields = ['dt_transaco','descricao','valor','categoria','observacoes']

field_descricao = TransacaoForm.base_fields["descricao"]
descricao.widget.attrs["class"] = "minha_classe_CSS"]
```

E pronto, ao usar um dos métodos para renderizar esse formulário, o campo
"descricao" vai ver com `class="minha_classe_CSS" em seu elemento Input.

Se quiser mudar a classe do Label e HTML do que vem em volta do Input também, nesse caso, vai ter que criar sua própria classe de widget, e customizar tudo.

Comment: Valeu cara realmente funcionou!